# What happens to existing workspaces after upgrading to TFS 2010

Tags: upgrade, workspace

I was looking for some insight about what happens to existing workspaces and files that are already checked-out on people, after an upgrade to TFS2010. Surprisingly enough I can not find any satisfactory information on this. (I am talking about upgrading on new hardware by the way. Fresh TFS instance, upgraded databases)

I've checked TFS Installation guide, I searched through the web, all I could find is upgrade scenarios for the server side. Nobody even mentions what happens to source control clients.

I've created a virtual machine to test the upgrade process, The upgrade was successful and all my files and workspaces exist in the new server too. The problem is: The new TFS installation has a new instanceID. When I redirected on the clients to the new server, the client seemed unable to match files and file states in the workspace with the ones on the new server. This makes me wonder if it will be possible to keep working after the production upgrade.

As I mentioned above I can not find anything on this, it would be great if anyone could point me to some paper or blog post about this.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do an upgrade your server ID should stay the same. You may need to chnage it is you want to clone your enviroment.

In your test senario you are creating a clone of the TFS server rather than a strate upgrade.

[ChangeServerID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee349259.aspx)

You are probably running into problems as this has been run on your test envionment to facilitate it runing on the same network as your production TFS server.

Comment: I understand that the serverID will not change if I do an in-place upgrade but I am planning an upgrade on new hardware so while upgrading things will be same as upgrading on my test VM. Fresh TFS instance, upgraded databases.
The only difference is, unlike the test server, the new production server will have the same server name as the old production server. 
Will giving the same name be enough to take over old workspaces or am I expected to change the instanceId explicitly?

Comment: The ID is taken with the databases. that is why you need to follow a clone procedure if you are trying to have a copy of the DB's restored. If you are turning off the old production while you upgrade on new production then you should not have that requirement.

You will NOT need to chnage the instance ID.

Comment: Thanks, this makes me feel better :)

Answer (score 0):

All workspaces and shelvesets remain unchanged, and people will be able to continue working immediately. Even checked-out files are OK and will be picked up correctly.

I would recommend upgrading the server first, and keep the clients as 2008 (using the Forward Compatibility Pack), and then upgrading the clients to 2010 as and when the projects are upgraded.